# How to correctly initialise a struct in C

Tags: arrays, c, struct

I'm working on a small project in C and I want to allocate structs in a function and add them to an array of structs.

For some reason, when I go to print the contents of the array of structs, I appear to start printing from unallocated memory.

A minimum working example is provided below:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// This struct simply stores a list and its size
struct list {
    int* values;
    size_t size;
};

// This function initialises an array of lists
// of size len, which each list (i.e. list.values)
// having a size of list_len
// `lists` is an array of pointers to lists
void list_init(struct list** lists, size_t len, size_t list_len) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        struct list list;
        list.values = malloc(sizeof(int) * list_len);
        list.size = list_len;
        lists[i] = &list;
    }
}

void main() {
    int len = 3;
    struct list* lists[len];
    list_init(lists, len, 5);

    // Print lists
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("list %zu: ", i);
        printf("size: %zu\n", lists[i]->size);
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 5; j++) { // Using 5 instead of lists[i]->size for obvious reasons
            printf("%d ", lists[i]->values[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

The output I would expect from this is:

```
list 0: size: 5
0 0 0 0 0
list 1: size: 5
0 0 0 0 0
list 2: size: 5
0 0 0 0 0
```

but instead I get:

```
list 0: size: 5
0 0 0 0 0 
list 1: size: 140727488332736
0 0 0 0 0 
list 2: size: 140727488332736
0 0 0 0 0
```

which is a pretty clear sign that I'm accessing memory that I'm not supposed to.

I noticed that rather than declaring the list with `struct list list;`, if I declare the list by allocating memory to a pointer with `struct list* list = malloc(sizeof(struct list));` the program gives the expected output. Why is that? If I want to create the object, rather than a pointer, how can I do that properly.

---

*P.S.: I am aware that I could just initialise `list` as a pointer. This question is mostly asking why **can't** I initialise it as an object*

Comment: The local `struct list list` in `list_init` is gone when the function ends (it is a local variable!). The pointer you store in the array is then dangling. Data intended to survive function returns must be global (or function static), or dynamically allocated (the typical case, which then opens the can of worms of ownership). One way to solve this is to define `lists` in main not as a list of pointers but indeed as a list of objects. You can still initialize them in a separate function (if you are unhappy with value initialization via `struct list lists[len] = {};`).

Comment: As an aside, I would advise to use different names for types and variables. Yes, struct tags live in a namespace separate from other identifiers in C but it is still not conducive to intelligibility. I'm also not sure what happens when you port your code to C++ and want to omit the redundant keyword `struct` in new code (transition to C++ is always a future possibility and should not be lightly squandered).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica That makes a lot of sense. Just to be sure, does this mean there are two ways I could implement this? Could I make `lists` EITHER an array of `struct list` and initialise the elements with `struct list list;` OR an array of `struct list` pointers and `malloc` the memory in the function. (Also, you're right about the variable/type naming. I was a little ashamed when I was proofreading my question ;-) )

Comment: Yes, correct. If you have an array of lists you can directly write to the members of the array elements, no need for a local struct any more.

Answer (score 0):

These statements within the function `list_init`

```
struct list list;
//...
lists[i] = &list;
```

does not make a sense because the local object list will not be alive after exiting the function. So you will have an array of invalid pointers of the type `struct list *`.

You need to allocate dynamically each object of the type `struct list` that will be pointed to by an element of the array.

The function can be declared and defined for example the following way

```
size_t list_init( struct list **lists, size_t len, size_t list_len ) 
{
    size_t count = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < len; i++ ) 
    {
        lists[i] = malloc( sizeof( struct list ) );
        
        if ( lists[i] != NULL )
        {
            ++count;
            
            lists[i]->size = 0;

            lists[i]->values = malloc( sizeof( int ) * list_len );
            
            if ( lists[i]->values != NULL ) lists[i]->size = list_len;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Also as the function does not initialize the allocated array pointed to by the data member values then this loop in main

```
    for (size_t j = 0; j < 5; j++) { // Using 5 instead of lists[i]->size for obvious reasons
        printf("%d ", lists[i]->values[j]);
    }
```

will invoke undefined behavior.

You could zero initialize the arras by using calloc instead of malloc. For example

```
lists[i]->values = calloc( list_len, sizeof( int ) );
```

And pay attention to that according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Here is your updated program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// This struct simply stores a list and its size
struct list 
{
    int* values;
    size_t size;
};

size_t list_init( struct list **lists, size_t len, size_t list_len ) 
{
    size_t count = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < len; i++ ) 
    {
        lists[i] = malloc( sizeof( struct list ) );
        
        if ( lists[i] != NULL )
        {
            ++count;
            
            lists[i]->size = 0;

            lists[i]->values = calloc( list_len, sizeof( int ));
            
            if ( lists[i]->values != NULL ) lists[i]->size = list_len;
        }
    }

    return count;
}


int main(void) 
{
    size_t len = 3;
    struct list* lists[len];
    
    list_init(lists, len, 5);

    // Print lists
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < len; i++ ) 
    {
        printf( "list %zu: ", i );
        
        if ( lists[i] != NULL )
        {
            printf( "size: %zu\n", lists[i]->size );
            for (size_t j = 0; j < lists[i]->size; j++) 
            {
                printf( "%d ", lists[i]->values[j] );
            }
            
            printf("\n");
        }           
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
list 0: size: 5
0 0 0 0 0 
list 1: size: 5
0 0 0 0 0 
list 2: size: 5
0 0 0 0 0
```

Of course you need to add a code to your program that will free all the allocated memory in the function `list_init`.

Answer (score 0):

You save the references to the same local variable and it is an UB. Also malloced memory is lost. Your main is also wrong.

I would do it this way (`calloc` is used as in main you print not initialized allocated memory):

```
typedef struct list {
    size_t size;
    int values[];
}list;

list **list_init(list **array, size_t size, size_t list_len) 
{
    list **wrk;
    if(!array) wrk = malloc(sizeof(*wrk) * size);
    else wrk = array; 
    if(wrk)
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            list *list = calloc(1, sizeof(*list) + list_len * sizeof(list -> values[0]));
            /* check for allocation errors!!!! */
            list -> size  = list_len;
            wrk[i] = list;
        }
    return wrk;
}

int main(void) {
    size_t len = 3;
    list **lists;
    
    /* if you pass NULL it will create the list of lists itself */
    lists = list_init(NULL, len, 5);
    /* check for allocation errors!!!! */

    // Print lists
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("list %zu: ", i);
        printf("size: %zu\n", lists[i]->size);
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 5; j++) { // Using 5 instead of lists[i]->size for obvious reasons
            printf("%d ", lists[i]->values[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) free(lists[i]);
    free(lists);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/9TPe1sM1a